How to get the value of the clicked bar in a BarChart (JavaFx)?
I need to get the X and Y axis values of a bar in a JavaFX BarChart when it is clicked, in order to process and save this data. Using the MVC architecture, I have to separate the view containing the BarChart from the controller where the event handler for the bars of the BarChart is present. I am therefore unable to get the x or y value of the clicked bar because once in the handler, I no longer have the possibility to retrieve the clicked bar. I have seen some people take the value of the data in the for loop where the listeners are attached to the bars, and use that, but obviously, this does not return the clicked bar, but the last one to which the listener was attached. So, once I am in the event handler in the controller, how can I retrieve the clicked bar? The controller and view code follow.
Controller:
EventHandler<MouseEvent> statsBarButtonHandler = new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println("PASSO AI GENERI E ARTISTI");
                StatisticsHandler statDomain = new StatisticsHandler();
              
                mainStage.setScene(genreView);
            }
        };

        for (XYChart.Data<Number, String> data : typeView.getTypeSerie().getData()) {
            data.getNode().setOnMouseClicked(statsBarButtonHandler);
            this.dataClicked = data;
        }

BarCHart:
BarChart <Number, String> barChart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
XYChart.Series<Number, String> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        this.typeSerie=series;

        // 
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(0, "Category 1"));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(14, "Category 2"));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(72, "Category 3"));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(55, "Category 4"));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(100, "Category 5"));

        // Aggiunta della serie al grafico
        barChart.getData().add(series);

Remember that, having to use the MVC architecture, I cannot put a controller in the view; they must remain separate. So I need to find a way to get the value directly in the handler of the controller.
As I already mentioned, I tried what I found on some sites to get the clicked bar from the for loop where the listener is attached, as shown here, but as output, I always get the last associated category, which is 5, and not the clicked one.
private XYChart.Data dataClicked;


EventHandler<MouseEvent> statsBarButtonHandler = new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println("PASSO AI GENERI E ARTISTI");
                StatisticsHandler statDominio = new StatisticsHandler();

                System.out.println(dataClicked.getYValue());
                
            }
        };

        for (XYChart.Data<Number, String> data : typeView.getTypeSerie().getData()) {
            data.getNode().setOnMouseClicked(statsBarButtonHandler);
            this.dataClicked = data;
        }


Use a different handler for each node

EventHandlers are elements of the View, not the Controller. Ideally, the EventHandler would pass the required information (the bar chart data element, not the x/y coordinates) to the Controller. Most likely, the Controller will then invoke an application logic method in the Model in response to this.

As pointed out by DaveB:

EventHandlers are elements of the View, not the Controller. Ideally, the EventHandler would pass the required information (the bar chart data element, not the x/y coordinates) to the Controller. Most likely, the Controller will then invoke an application logic method in the Model in response to this.

The example below assumed you were already doing this; I missed that you were defining the event handler in the controller. You should have the controller register a listener with the view. Then the view's event handlers would invoke that listener with the needed state when appropriate. And then the controller would react as needed.
Also, in case you're using FXML, note that an MVC controller and an FXML controller are not the same thing. An FXML controller is actually part of the view in the context of MVC (and other similar architectures).

The best solution, in my opinion (and James_D's), is to register a unique EventHandler with each data's node. That will allow you to know which data's node was clicked because only one such node could have triggered the handler. The below shows an example of this, though not in the context of MVC.
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(Main.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("X");

    var yAxis = createCategoryAxis();

    var chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    chart.getData().add(createSeries(yAxis.getCategories()));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(chart, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private CategoryAxis createCategoryAxis() {
    var yAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    yAxis.setLabel("Y");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      yAxis.getCategories().add("Category " + i);
    }
    return yAxis;
  }

  private XYChart.Series<Number, String> createSeries(List<String> categories) {
    var random = new Random();

    var series = new XYChart.Series<Number, String>();
    series.setName("Series");
    for (var category : categories) {
      var data = new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(random.nextInt(1, 20), category);
      // Note 'subscribe' was added in JavaFX 21. If using an older version you can do
      // something similar with a ChangeListener.
      data.nodeProperty().subscribe((oldNode, newNode) -> {
        if (oldNode != null) oldNode.setOnMouseClicked(null);
        if (newNode != null) {
          // Unique EventHandler for each XYChart.Data instance. This makes it easy to know
          // which XYChart.Data's node was clicked, since the instance is captured.
          newNode.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            e.consume();
            var x = data.getXValue();
            var y = data.getYValue();
            // This would be where you notify the controller's listener
            System.out.printf("Data node clicked: '%s' = %d%n", y, x);
          });
        }
      });
      series.getData().add(data);
    }
    return series;
  }
}


The key thing here is that you've defined the EventHandler in the layout code, where it belongs. This breaks the OP's requirement, based on a misunderstanding about MVC, that it be in the Controller.

True. I missed that part of the question.

This is good.  I hate "Dispatch Event Handlers", especially in the era of lambdas.  One thing I would do differently is to not use a "Listener" but pass the View (or the View builder - which in this case is createSeries()) a functional element to call.  In this case, it would be a BiConsumer<X,Y>, or a consumer of a custom class with the info.  Then the EventHandler would invoke the Consumer.  It's a little more direct than a Listener.

Making a chart interactive is a common use-case. To minimize coupling, this usually proceeds in two phases:

The controller arranges a listener for each element of interest, say a bar in a chart.

This example adds a single listener, caching the desired values. While economical, the result is stale values if the original data mutates. Instead, create individual handler instances and access the data of each from the enclosing scope, for example:
var clicked = new SimpleStringProperty();
for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> series : chart.getData()) {
    for (Data<String, Number> data : series.getData()) {
        data.getNode().setOnMouseClicked((var t) -> {
            clicked.set("Data: " + data.getXValue() + " = " + data.getYValue());
        });
    }
}

As another way to add individual handlers, this example illustrates the subscribe() method, which can adapt to more complex mutations.

The listener responds by updating the view as desired.

In the example below using jfreechart-fx, the Handler adds a ChartMouseListenerFX that can identify the target bar when fired. The listener then queries the chart's data and updates a StringProperty accordingly. Note that the controller can simply bind() the Label to display the result. See also these examples.

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.CategoryItemEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.ChartEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.fx.ChartViewer;
import org.jfree.chart.fx.interaction.ChartMouseEventFX;
import org.jfree.chart.fx.interaction.ChartMouseListenerFX;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/78593695/230513
 */
public class BarChartJFCFX extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var chartViewer = new ChartViewer();
        var handler = new Handler(chartViewer);
        var label = new Label();
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18; -fx-padding: 5");
        label.textProperty().bind(handler.clickedProperty());
        var root = new StackPane(chartViewer);
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        StackPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
        stage.setTitle("BarChart JFreeChart FX");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    private static final class Handler {
        
        private static final String PROMPT = "Click on a bar.";
        private final StringProperty clicked;
        
        public StringProperty clickedProperty() {
            return clicked;
        }
        
        public Handler(ChartViewer view) {
            this.clicked = new SimpleStringProperty(PROMPT);
            view.setChart(createChart(createDataset()));
            view.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListenerFX() {
                @Override
                public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEventFX e) {
                    ChartEntity ce = e.getEntity();
                    if (ce instanceof CategoryItemEntity cie) {
                        var data = cie.getDataset();
                        var rowKey = cie.getRowKey();
                        var colKey = cie.getColumnKey();
                        var value = data.getValue(rowKey, colKey);
                        clicked.set(rowKey + ", " + colKey + " = " + value);
                    } else {
                        clicked.set(PROMPT);
                    }
                }
                
                @Override
                public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEventFX event) {
                }
            });
        }
        
        private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {
            var chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "Bar Chart", "Category", "Value", dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false
            );
            return chart;
        }
        
        private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {
            // row keys...
            var series1 = "Series 1";
            var series2 = "Series 2";
            // column keys...
            var category1 = "Category 1";
            var category2 = "Category 2";
            var category3 = "Category 3";
            var dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            dataset.addValue(1.0, series1, category1);
            dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, category2);
            dataset.addValue(3.0, series1, category3);
            dataset.addValue(5.0, series2, category1);
            dataset.addValue(7.0, series2, category2);
            dataset.addValue(6.0, series2, category3);
            return dataset;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


This answer shows how to do this using one EventHandler. This may be considered a hack. I don't believe it is. This takes the important information and stores it as a Pair using the node setUserData method. That data can then be available in the EventHandler. Note: You don't have to use a Pair.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Pair;

public class App extends Application {
    final static String austria = "Austria";
    final static String brazil = "Brazil";
    final static String france = "France";
    final static String italy = "Italy";
    final static String usa = "USA";

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String,Number> bc = new BarChart(xAxis,yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");       
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");       
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 20148.82));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 10000));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 35407.15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 12000));      

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 57401.85));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 41941.19));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 45263.37));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 117320.16));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 14845.27));  

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 45000.65));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 44835.76));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 18722.18));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 17557.31));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 92633.68));  

        Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
        bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        
        for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> series : bc.getData()) {            
            for(Data data : series.getData())
            {
                data.getNode().setUserData(new Pair(data.getXValue(), data.getYValue()));
                data.getNode().setOnMouseClicked(mouseClickedEventHandler);
            }                                  
        }
        
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(App.class);
    }
    
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseClickedEventHandler = (MouseEvent t) -> {
        Node clickedNode = (Node)t.getSource();
        Pair<String, Number> pair = (Pair)clickedNode.getUserData();
        System.out.println("Data node clicked: " + pair.getKey()+ " = " + pair.getValue());
    };
}

Output
Data node clicked: USA = 92633.68
Data node clicked: USA = 14845.27
Data node clicked: USA = 12000
Data node clicked: USA = 12000
Data node clicked: USA = 12000
Data node clicked: USA = 12000
Data node clicked: Italy = 35407.15
Data node clicked: Italy = 117320.16
Data node clicked: Italy = 17557.31
Data node clicked: USA = 12000
Data node clicked: Brazil = 41941.19
Data node clicked: Brazil = 20148.82
Data node clicked: Austria = 57401.85


I wouldn't consider it a hack,but.... This methodology implies that the Controller (or at least some code outside the View) is establishing the EventHandler and passing to the View.  In this case, it's essentially a global variable.  This means that some code outside the View has to have knowledge of the contents of the View to some degree.  For instance, it's a MouseEvent, but what if it's changed to a keyboard event, or a Button action?  Also, it has to know that the Nodes have this data.  In any event, it violates the reason for using MVC in the first place.

More details here; please feel free to adapt from this variation of your example.

@trashgod, good solution, but I think it uses multiple EventHandlers like Slaw's answer. If you look at the OP's original code, the OP attempts to do this using one EventHandler for all the nodes. That is what I was trying to show here. I was trying to show how to do it using only one EventHandler for all the nodes.

@SedJ601: I agree; I meant with respect to minimizing the use of raw types; IIRC, the extraValue property of Data was another place to cache each (nominal) pair.
